# WP7 simultaneous recording and playing sound

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I need to play a short sound repeatedly (simulating metronome) while recording sound.
What I did for the metronome was basically setting a DispatcherTimer with specific Interval, and every tick firing a SoundEffect. For the recorder I call the XNA's FrameworkDispatcher.Update method every 33 milisec (also using DispatcherTimer for that).

I run the metronome, it works fine, and then when I begin to record - there's a short break in playing sound (hard to say if it delays the Interval or just mutes the sound), and after a while (when already recording), the metronome continues to tick, but with more 'flatten' sound.

Is this a hardware limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I thinkt this is connected with hardware. I was making an app to modify sound when it is captured. When I was using headset (with mic) connected to device there was big echo on playback. When I was using only headphones (and device mic) everything was ok. It was tested on HTC and Nokia - same results but HTC was little bit better :)